# Collapse button is not showing for Bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Online Notes</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am new to bootstrap and when I try to add a navbar using bootstrap, the collapse menu is not showing the three icon-bar. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing it completely wrong. Here is collapsing Navbar code I used to design my Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
     <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="images/123.png" class="d-inline-block" width="70" height="70" alt="">Spaceyfi </a>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
             <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="#explore" class="nav-link">Explore</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="#contactUs" class="nav-link">Team</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="#contactUs" class="nav-link">Gallery</a></li>
             </ul>
       </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Now, You are missing so many important tags and class for example

```
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

This is used to display those three lines, The `data-target` is used to tell the elements which should be inside collapsed menu.

i.e after declaring `data-target="#navbarCollapse"` , I used the same ID in

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
```

to tell the stuff that goes inside the collapsed menu.

Try going through official bootstrap documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I found the problem. I was trying to use the content of bootstrap 3.3.7 and I added the CDN of bootstrap 4.0.0.

Comment: I haven't used Boostrap 3 but something tells me that it might still not work.

But still in case you ever find my answer beneficial or useful, Do hit that up vote button